# Is the usage of tenses correct in this sentence - "two days had passed since she had last eaten or slept"

Tags: tense, past-tense, past-vs-past-perfect

> Two days had passed since she had last eaten or slept.

Or should it be:

> Two days have passed since she last ate or slept.

Or something else? And why? The combinatorial explosion of past simple, past perfect and present perfect is killing me.

Comment: Either sentence is correct, they just mean different things.  "Two days **have** passed" = "as of right now".  "Two days **had** passed" = "as of some point in the past that we're talking about."

Answer (score 3):

Both examples are fine (the *semantic* difference is simply whether the "narrative time" is in the present or the past).

But it's *unnecessary* to repeat the [Past Perfect](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/past_perfect_tense.htm) with ***she had last eaten*** in the first version, since it's contextually obvious she last ate/slept *before* the passage of the two days. As a rule, native speakers don't tend to use Past Perfect repeatedly because it's stylistically cumbersome. Consider...

> [*had passed since I **saw***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22had%20passed%20since%20I%20saw%22) - About 4,170 results in Google Books
>    [*had passed since I **had seen***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22had%20passed%20since%20I%20saw%22#tbm=bks&q=%22had%20passed%20since%20I%20had%20seen%22) - About 2,170 results

In short, example #1 is a valid construction, but I personally probably wouldn't use Past Perfect for the second clause. If you want to make things easier for yourself as a learner, I suggest you do likewise.

Comment: But I used Present Perfect in the second example, "Two days **have** passed". Is it also correct? Can you just interchange had with have here?

Comment: I think you're getting confused between ***Present** Perfect* and ***Past** Perfect*. I can say *Right now, one hour **has** passed since I answered* - that's a ***present** [perfect]* usage. But if I want to talk about something in the past, it has to be *At the time when I answered [in the past] one hour ago **had** passed since the question was posted*. In that second case I'd be using ***past** [perfect]* because my "narrative reference time" (when I answered) is *already* in the past, and I want to refer to something even earlier than that.

Comment: I have to admit that I don't grok the "narrative reference time" thing. Could you try to explain it, please?

Comment: *I **see** it **now*** (reference time is the present moment, time of speaking). *I **saw** it **then*** (reference time is somewhen in the past). In just the same way we can contrast *I have understood it now* (**present** perfect) and *I had understood it then* (**past** perfect).

Comment: Isn't present perfect supposed to represent an action completed in the past at unspecified time?  _I have understood it **now**_ makes no sense to me, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Locaha: the 'present' bit in 'present perfect' is because although it started in the past, it is either still happening or some aspect of it is still in force. "I have worked here for five years" ... still happening "I have reserved a room for tonight"... the reservation is still in force.

Comment: **"I have worked here for five years" ... still happening.** Oh, great. This just goes against all the tutorials I have found so far... AAARGH tenses are impossible...

Comment: @FumbleFingers (or shall I say F⚡︎F) - Is it time to invoke the rearward-looking eyeball, or would that not help the OP here? (http://i.stack.imgur.com/m0fS8.png)

Comment: @Locaha: ***No!*** Present Perfect doesn't *necessarily* imply "still happening" - but it *always* implies "relevant to time of utterance". So I could say *I have worked in France for five years, and in Italy for three, but I live in London now,* for example - the fact that I ***did*** work abroad (but not now) is somehow "relevant" to the current conversation, that's all.

Comment: I still can't understand the difference of meanings between using past perfect and present perfect in my example sentences.

Comment: *23 hours **have** passed since you posted this question* means there are 23 hours between when you posted and ***now*** (the time when I'm writing this comment, the *present*). If I want to refer to some amount of time that passed *in the past*, I'd use Past Perfect: *When JavaLatte posted his comment, 20 hours **had** passed since the question was asked*. I don't know how to put it any clearer than that.

Comment: No, no, I think I'm starting to get it... The question is, what would a narrator in a novel use?

Comment: Most novels are written in the past tense. But this is a *stylistic choice,* and I don't see how knowing that will help you learn the basics of English tenses.

Comment: Well, I learned English from books, mostly, so understanding why the author used this or that tense would be nice...

Comment: Well, I don't want to sound dismissive, but if I had realized you were only asking about the difference between *two days **have** passed* and *two days **had** passed*, I probably wouldn't have posted an answer at all (it's a bit basic, even for ELL). To my mind, the only potential difficulty here is deciding whether or not to *repeat* the Past Perfect in your first example. And so far as I know there is no "rule" for that, only a *tendency*.

Comment: @Locaha: I must just say that I *still* don't understand why this particular point has been causing problems for you - particularly since your text in both the question and comments suggest you actually have quite a *good* grasp of English. But maybe that's because I'm a native speaker, so it's not easy for me to put myself in the position of someone who doesn't have *that* level of familiarity with the language. Whatever - I'm glad if you've learned something here, and I look forward to seeing what *else* you might want to know about.

Comment: The funny thing is, I can read books perfectly well without a deep understanding of English tenses, I just seem to get everything from the context. But nowadays I'm trying to _write_ a book in English. Yeah, it's much harder...

Comment: I know when it comes to [**receptive** vs **productive** vocabulary](https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/booknook/receptive-vs-productive-vocabulary/), there are many words that I'd *understand* perfectly well, even though I might never actually *use* them. Perhaps in your case you've become used to understanding the "core" meaning of verbs without taking much notice of the tenses themselves. You'll just have to work at it a bit harder! :)